# Assigning and returning objects in java

Tags: java, object, return, assign

[image: this is the output that i get]I am trying to assign the current array element in the temp array with the Student object returned after calling the getStudent method.... I called the getStudent method (Step 2) and have temp[i] = to assign the current element in the temp array but cannot figure out what it should = to pair it up with the Student object returned. When using getStudent() and running the program, the output is enter the number of students, the user enters the number, and that is all that happens, it does not ask for the user to enter the name and etc, I'm not sure if step 2 is the problem or if there is another issue entirely.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Students
{
  private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Student[] students;

    students = getStudents();
    printStudents(students);
  }

  private static Student[] getStudents()
  {
    Student[] temp;
    int       how_many;

    System.out.print("How many students? ");
    how_many = input.nextInt();
    purgeInputBuffer();
    temp =  new Student[input.nextInt()];  // Step 1 ???
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
    {
      getStudent();         // Step 2
      temp[i] =      ;    //  <----------    
    }
    return temp;    // Step 3
  }

  private static Student getStudent()
 {
    String name,
        address,
          major;
     double gpa;

    System.out.print("Enter name: ");
    name = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter address: ");
    address = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter major: ");
    major = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter GPA: ");
    gpa = input.nextDouble();
    purgeInputBuffer();

    return new Student (name, address, major, gpa);     // Step 4
  }

  private static void printStudents(Student[] s)
  {
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++)    // Step 5
    {
      System.out.println(getStudent());     // Step 6
    }
  }

  private static void purgeInputBuffer()
  {
    // ----------------------------------------------------
    // Purge input buffer by reading and ignoring remaining
    // characters in input buffer including the newline
    // ----------------------------------------------------
    input.nextLine();
  }
}
```

Comment: why not to use this: `temp[i] = getStudent();// Step 2` ?

Comment: when using that and running the program, the output is enter the number of students, the user enters the number, and that is all that happens, it does not ask for the user to enter the name and etc

Comment: I'm quite sure what @Cootri said is what you should do. But please do also look at your `private static void printStudents(Student[] s)` method and acutally on the line `//step 6` i don't believe that is how you want to be doing that. Instead you want `System.out.println(s[i]);` not `System.out.println(getStudent());` For my code substitution to work though you will need to Override the `toString` method so it can acutally display the information

Comment: Your code isn't working properly because of the line `temp = new Student[input.nextInt()];` in that line you have already asked the user for an int of how many student's here `how_many = input.nextInt();` So you should just simply do `temp = new Student[how_many];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first problem is first on the line:

`temp = new Student[input.nextInt()];`

in that line you have already asked the user to enter how many Students and store it in `how_many`. So i'm assuming you want to instead do:

`temp = new Student[how_many];`

Also what i said in my comment:

But please do also look at your `private static void printStudents(Student[] s)` method and acutally on the line //step 6 i don't believe that is how you want to be doing that. Instead you want `System.out.println(s[i]);` not `System.out.println(getStudent());` For my code substitution to work though you will need to Override the toString method so it can actually display the information

Comment: That does allow the program to continue, but continues to ask the questions past the how many number inputted

Comment: @Brent Did you change the second thing i mentioned

Comment: yes i changed the second thing....it must be a for statement problem? not entirely sure

Comment: @Brent You're for loop looks correct. Is there anything in the student class where you ask for information if so you should remove that.

Comment: I added a picture of what the outcome is @3kings

Comment: @Beeeee I still don't think you fixed the second problem that i said to fix. Do you mind updating your code and maybe including the Student class?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108425/discussion-between-beeeee-and-3kings).